# How to add Python and the Python Scripts directory to a PATH variable?

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to add Python and the Python scripts directory to the PATH variable. Here is the command I'm writing into CMD (I'm using Windows 8.1):

```cs
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\", "User")
```

But CMD returns this:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Anyway, may please someone give me an example? How should I write command above into windows's CMD?

---

None of these work:

```cs
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("C:/", "$env:Path;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "C:/;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\", "User")
```

Comment: have u added python path in windows for executing. If not try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

In windows command prompt:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\
```

Explanation:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;  -- takes the current path and sets PATH to it.
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\      -- Adds your directories to the path
```

Is this what you were after?

Comment: Thank you, upvote. I entered your command and I think it worked, because there wasn't any error. But you know, I'm trying to use implement [this](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/install.html). Please scroll down to see *"Installation On Windows"* paragraph. Now when I write this command `pip install mitmproxy`, it says *"'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*. Any idea?

Comment: In order to use pip you have to install pip - and you can't use pip to install pip because pip is not installed :D ... So install pip first ...

Comment: @Raffe81 : could you provide also an example of doing the same from within a Python script?

Comment: @Claudio pip is included in Python 2.7.9+ by default

Comment: import sys

sys.path.append("C:\Python27") And then the same for your scripts path.

Comment: Regarding pip. If it is installed, what folder is it in? Is that folder in your PATH? Also if you just added the directories to your PATH I think you need to open a new command prompt for the changes to be affective.